Strange IP address in Gateway column of route output?
I am trying to diagnose a problem with networking connectivity interruptions between my macOS host and a UTM guest VM. The connection will suddenly drop, with the host unable to reach the VM anymore. I currently suspect a problem with the routing table in macOS.
When looking at the output of route, I could not find an explanation for some strange Gateway entries, which do not look like either v4 or v6 IPs?
$ netstat -rn -f inet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.178.1      UGScg                 en0
default            link#24            UCSIg           bridge100      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#15            UCS                   en0      !
169.254.169.254    link#15            UHLSW                 en0      !
192.168.64         link#24            UC              bridge100      !
192.168.64.1       62.3e.5f.73.14.64  UHLWI                 lo0
192.168.64.2       8a.c3.94.a.86.e2   UHLWIi          bridge100   1088
192.168.178        link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1/32   link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1      dc:15:c8:ef:b8:1d  UHLWIir               en0   1197
192.168.178.24     1c:1a:df:76:df:f8  UHLWI                 en0      !
192.168.178.52/32  link#15            UCS                   en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCS                  en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWIg         bridge100
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCS                   en0      !

The VM is 192.168.64.2 -- note the Gateway of 8a.c3.94.a.86.e2. What is this? I have never seen an IP address formatted this way, or is this some other kind of destination identifier?

They are probably ARP records.

This is a link address translation entry, flagged L. So it’s probably a MAC address. Why does it look like this? Possibly an artifact of how QEMU does networking in your setup.

Yes, thanks, you're right -- this appears to be some kind of virtual link layer address. I am not sure why it uses periods instead of colons, the output of arp as I found out, uses colons instead.

Those are most likely the resolved MAC addresses – macOS uses a single table both as a routing table and as an ARP cache.
Fundamentally the purpose of the 'Gateway' field is to define a MAC-layer destination, not a network-layer one – we just usually do that indirectly, by specifying an IP address of the gateway (or an interface) and letting the OS use ARP to resolve it to the actual MAC address.

For example, Gateway: 192.168.178.1 doesn't mean "Send to 192.168.178.1", it means "Do an ARP lookup of 192.168.178.1 and send to that MAC address".

Similarly, the link#24 field doesn't mean "Send via interface #24" – that's not enough for Ethernet – it really means "Do an ARP lookup of the destination IP, get the MAC address, and send to that MAC via interface #24".


The result of this ARP lookup is usually cached in a separate table (the ARP cache) in other operating systems, but it means you have two tables which do more-or-less the same thing (mapping an IP to some kind of MAC), so it seems that macOS (and I believe also FreeBSD) has chosen to use the same table for both.
So if you have 192.168.64.2 as the destination, after the 192.168.64 -> link#24 lookup is done and an ARP query is made, the OS adds a direct 192.168.64.2 -> 8a.c3.94.a.86.e2 entry to avoid having to repeat the ARP query for future packets. (Note the L "link-layer" flag and the presence of an Expire field for this entry.)
As to why the addresses are formatted differently, from taking a look at FreeBSD's netstat it seems that "bridge" interfaces have a distinct type from "ethernet" (IFT_BRIDGE vs IFT_ETHER) and I suspect the macOS netstat just ended up using two different functions for formatting the address into text...

Great explanation, thank you! Any idea why this network interface wouldn't show up in ifconfig? If these are mac addresses of network interfaces, shouldn't they appear in the ether field here? The man page for ifconfig also says: "The address addr is specified as a series of colon-separated hex digits." but even if I were to replace periods with colons, these addresses are not mapped here anywhere.

Thanks for explaining ARP as well; when I run arp work (work is the VM hostname), I see this: work (192.168.64.2) at 8a:c3:94:a:86:e2 on bridge100 ifscope [bridge]. So it really is just the interface address with periods instead of colons. Still not sure why that interface is not listed in ifconfig though.

They won't show up in your ifconfig because they are the MAC addresses of those destinations, i.e. interfaces belonging to remote hosts (it makes no sense to have your own MAC address in that field). I suppose that if UTM is doing something weird with bridge networking, they might not necessarily be valid MAC addresses, but overall this still remains the general interpretation – the entries have the L flag (and an expiry), so they're still ARP-cache entries.

Ah of course, makes sense! I'm running UTM in Shared network mode, which creates a VLAN. So this address is probably addressing some "virtual node" (virtual router?) in that network. I'm not sure, clearly my networking knowledge is sparse at best.

If you say 192.168.64.2 is the VM, then I'd expect the MAC to literally be the VM's MAC (just like how it would work on a physical ethernet) – there shouldn't be a "virtual router" for same-subnet traffic. Does the MAC correspond to what your virtual machine itself is showing through its ifconfig?

Looks like it corresponds to this interface on the VM: enp0s1: connected to enp0s1 | "Red Hat Virtio" | ethernet (virtio_net), 8A:C3:94:0A:86:E2, hw, mtu 1500. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
